# Light emitting object

Tags: light

Is there any way to replicate the image in eevee? I have tried the emission node or even placing some hidden lights but I just can't get the light to behave how I want it to. On cycles it looks exactly how I want it to, but on eevee its like it doesnt bounce the light correctly. Any tips?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PplcC.jpg

[image]

Comment: You have to use an `Irradiance Volume`[https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/light_probes/irradiance_volumes.html] and bake the light in order to simulate global illumination near the emission surfaces.

Comment: Hi. Please add any relevant images using the built-in uploader: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post . Thanks.